# Manipulation of server characteristics through a hosted website in IIS

Tags: c#, iis

I'd like to understand and discuss below topics about a Website being hosted in IIS.

1. is there **ANYWAY** to manipulate a server's characteristics , like changing the Date & Time of the server itself, from a hosted website(!)? (e.g.  The Environment: IIS 7.5, Windows Server 2008R2 and a website written in ASP.NET 3.5 - Criteria: By coding in C#, can we manipulate the Date & Time of the server itself FROM 6/11/2014 10:05:25 TO 10/10/2015 11:11:26 - via any EXISTING API)
2. Is there **ANYWAY** to execute a program(e.g. a **BATCH** file or an **EXE** file) from a hosted website in IIS by code?(like executing a batch file to do certain jobs)

i'm **NOT** looking for the ways it can be done(e.g. Remote Access to the server or ...), rather to just know that are these manipulations possible(via an API for example) through a website hosted by IIS or not.

the comments are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Given the according security permissions to the authenticated website user or the impersonating Application Pool user account (in case of anonymous user sessions), anything you expose through a website hosted by IIS is possible.

Comment: like changing time or executing a batch file? there is an api for those?

Comment: There's no readymade API for these tasks but as you mentioned changing the time can be done by coding in C# as well as excuting batch files via [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process.start%28v=vs.110%29).